# Make scrollbars always visible using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

I want to make my CSS always visible. I have 2 visibility versions for my code. I want to make my scrollbars always visible in one of the versions. I wanted to do it using jQuery. Is there a way to do that?

I want this CSS code to be in jQuery.

```css
 body {
  padding: 10px;
 }

 ul {
  max-height:150px;
  overflow:scroll;
  width: 250px;
 }

 ul::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 10px;
 }

 ul::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
 }
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>This is some content</li>
 <li>This is some content</li>
 <li>This is some content</li>
 <li>This is some content</li>
 <li>This is some content</li>
 <li>This is some content</li>
 <li>This is some content</li>
 <li>This is some content</li>
 <li>This is some content</li>
 <li>This is some content</li>
 <li>This is some content</li>
 <li>This is some content</li>
</ul>
```

I know its possible for the `body` and `ul` tags. How do I do it for the `::-webkit-scrollbar` and `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb`?